# Calculate Average time spend based on a change in location zone

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table similar to

```
create table LOCHIST
(
  RES_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  LOC_DATE TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  LOC_ZONE VARCHAR(10)
)
```

with values such as

```
insert into LOCHIST values(0911,2015-09-23 12:27:00.000000,SYLVSYLGA);
insert into LOCHIST values(5468,2013-02-15 13:13:24.000000,30726);
insert into LOCHIST values(23894,2013-02-15 13:12:13.000000,BECTFOUNC);
insert into LOCHIST values(24119,2013-02-15 13:12:09.000000,30363);
insert into LOCHIST values(7101,2013-02-15 13:11:37.000000,37711);
insert into LOCHIST values(26083,2013-02-15 13:11:36.000000,SHAWANDAL);
insert into LOCHIST values(24978,2013-02-15 13:11:36.000000,38132);
insert into LOCHIST values(26696,2013-02-15 13:11:27.000000,29583);
insert into LOCHIST values(5468,2013-02-15 13:11:00.000000,37760);
insert into LOCHIST values(5552,2013-02-15 13:10:55.000000,30090);
insert into LOCHIST values(24932,2013-02-15 13:10:48.000000,JBTTLITGA);
insert into LOCHIST values(23894,2013-02-15 13:10:42.000000,47263);
insert into LOCHIST values(26803,2013-02-15 13:10:25.000000,32534);
insert into LOCHIST values(24434,2013-02-15 13:10:03.000000,PLANSUFVA);
insert into LOCHIST values(26696,2013-02-15 13:10:00.000000,GEORALBGA);
insert into LOCHIST values(5468,2013-02-15 13:09:54.000000,19507);
insert into LOCHIST values(23894,2013-02-15 13:09:48.000000,37725);
```

This table literally goes on for millions of records.

Each RES_ID represents the ID of a trailer who pings their location to a LOC_ZONE which is then stored at the time in LOC_DATE.

What I am trying to find, is the average amount of time spent for all trailers in a specific location zone. For example, if trailer x spent 4 hours in in loc zone PLANSUFVA, and trailer y spent 6 hours in loc zone PLANSUFVA I would want to return

```
Loc Zone  Avg Time  
PLANSUFVA   5
```

Is there anyway to do this without cursors?

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Given the sample data you posted, what is the expected output that you would want and why?  Is there some distinction between numeric `LOC_ZONE` values and non-numeric `LOC_ZONE` values?  It would be very helpful if you modified your `INSERT` statements so that they were syntactically valid as well.

Comment: Why is this tagged both sql-server and Oracle?

Comment: For my purposes a numeric and non-numeric zone can be treated identically.

Comment: Do you need the average time per trailer overall, or the average time per stay (eg if trailer x started at A, then moved to B, then back to A, would that count as 2 stays at A)?

Comment: I need the average time any trailer spends at a location per each stay.

Comment: How do you define stay?

Comment: The amount of time from when a trailer pings at one location zone to when it pings at another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, you need the amount of time spent at each location.

One way to do this is with a correlated subquery.  You need to group adjacent values.  The idea is to find the next value in the sequence:

```
select resid, min(loc_zone) as loc_zone, min(loc_date) as StartTime,
       max(loc_date) as EndTime,
       nextdate as NextStartTime
from (select lh.*,
             (select min(loc_date) from lochist lh2
              where lh2.res_id = lh.res_id and lh2.loc_zone <> lh.loc_zone and
                    lh2.loc_date > lh.loc_date
             ) as nextdate
      from lochist lh
     ) lh
 group by lh.res_id, nextdate
```

With this data, you can then get the average that you want.

I am not clear if the time should be based on `EndTime - StartTime` (last recorded time at the location minus the first recorded time) or `NextStartTime - startTime` (first time at next location minus first time at this location).

Also, this returns NULL for the last location for each `res_id`.  You don't say what to do about the last in the sequence.

If you build an index on `res_id, loc_date, loc_zone`, it might run faster.

If you had Oracle or SQL Server 2012, the right query is:

```
select lh.*,
       lead(loc_date) over (partition by res_id order by loc_date) as nextdate
from (select lh.*,
             lag(loc_zone) over (partition by res_id order by loc_date) as prevzone
      from lochist lh
     ) lh
where prevzone is null or prevzone <> loc_zone
```

Now you have one row per stay and nextdate is the date at the next zone.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. The time should be based on first time at next location minus first time at this location. When I try to run your query, it trys to execute for about 5 minutes but never does, I think my table contains too much data.

Comment: @user2076550  . . . First try it on a subset of the data, such as one-day or one-month's worth.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The second query you posted works great but I have one concern. If a trailer pings at the same location say 5 times in a row (this error happens alot), then pings from a different location, won't this query only give the time from 5th ping to the 6th rather than the 1st to the 6th?

Answer (score 1):

This needs SQL 2012:

```
with data
as (
      select *, (case when LOC_ZONE != PREVIOUS_LOC_ZONE or PREVIOUS_LOC_ZONE is null then ROW_ID else null end) as STAY_START, (case when LOC_ZONE != NEXT_LOC_ZONE or NEXT_LOC_ZONE is null then ROW_ID else null end) as STAY_END
      from (
            select RES_ID, LOC_ZONE, LOC_DATE, lead(LOC_DATE, 1) over (partition by RES_ID, LOC_ZONE order by LOC_DATE) as NEXT_LOC_DATE, lag(LOC_ZONE, 1) over (partition by RES_ID order by LOC_DATE) as PREVIOUS_LOC_ZONE, lead(LOC_ZONE, 1) over (partition by RES_ID order by LOC_DATE) as NEXT_LOC_ZONE, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by RES_ID, LOC_ZONE, LOC_DATE) as ROW_ID
            from LOCHIST
      ) t
), stays  as (
      select * from (
            select RES_ID, LOC_ZONE, STAY_START, lead(STAY_END, 1) over (order by ROWID) as STAY_END
            from (
                  select RES_ID, LOC_ZONE, STAY_START, STAY_END, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by RES_ID, LOC_ZONE, STAY_START desc) as ROWID
                  from data
                  where STAY_START is not null or STAY_END is not null 
            ) t
      ) t
      where STAY_START is not null and STAY_END is not null
)
select s.LOC_ZONE, avg(datediff(second, LOC_DATE, NEXT_LOC_DATE)) / 60 / 60 as AVG_IN_HOURS
from data d
inner join stays s on d.RES_ID = s.RES_ID and d.LOC_ZONE = s.LOC_ZONE and d.ROW_ID >= s.STAY_START and d.ROW_ID < s.STAY_END
group by s.LOC_ZONE
```

Comment: I don't think you want to `partition by LOC_DATE`. Also, I think you skew the average by including a zero-length row for each partition (by `isnull(NEXT_LOCDATE, LOC_DATE)`)

Comment: That should LOC_ZONE! Updated. Also, you should be careful with this if a trailer is going to revisit locations

Comment: The thing about the average is also true - updated.  Good spot

Comment: The second version doesn't work, if someone can move back to the same zone more than once.

Comment: OK, I've updated this with the definition used for stay. I've also removed the other one. Interesting question. Do you have SQL 2012?

Answer (score 0):

To do this without using either a cursor or a correlated subquery, try:

```
with rl as
(select l.*, rank() over (partition by res_id order by loc_date) rn
 from lochist l),
fdr as
(select rc.*, coalesce(rn.loc_date, getdate()) next_date
 from rl rc
 left join rl rn on rc.res_id = rn.res_id and rc.rn + 1 = rn.rn)
select loc_zone, avg(datediff(second, loc_date, next_date))/3600 avg_time
from fdr
group by loc_zone
```

[SQLFiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/19f72/3)

(Because of the way that SQLServer calculates time differences, it's probably better to calculate the average time in seconds and then divide by 60*60. With the exception of the getdate() and datediff clauses - which can be replaced by `sysdate` and `next_date - loc_date` - this should work in both SQLServer 2005 onwards and Oracle 10g onwards.)

Answer (score 0):

This should get you each zone ordered by the average number of minutes spent in it. The `CROSS APPLY` returns the next ping in a different zone.

```
SELECT
     loc.LOC_ZONE
    ,AVG(DATEDIFF(mi,loc.LOC_DATE,nextPing.LOC_DATE)) AS avgMinutes
FROM LOCHIST loc
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 loc2.LOC_DATE
    FROM LOCHIST loc2
    WHERE loc2.RES_ID = loc.RES_ID
    AND loc2.LOC_DATE > loc.LOC_DATE
    AND loc2.LOC_ZONE <> loc.LOC_ZONE
    ORDER BY loc2.LOC_DATE ASC
) AS nextPing
GROUP BY loc.LOC_ZONE
ORDER BY avgMinutes DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I try to run this I get the following error:  An unexpected token "APPLY"
was found following "OM LOCHIST loc CROSS".  Expected
tokens may include:  "JOIN".  SQLSTATE=42601
Error Code: -104

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? `CROSS APPLY` will only work in 2005 and newer versions.

Comment: 2000, Thanks for letting me know. I am still very new at this

Answer (score 0):

My variation of the solution:

```
select LOC_ZONE, avg(TOTAL_TIME) AVG_TIME from (
    select RES_ID, LOC_ZONE, sum(TIME_SPENT) TOTAL_TIME
    from (
        select RES_ID, LOC_ZONE, datediff(mi, lag(LOC_DATE, 1) over (
            partition by RES_ID order by LOC_DATE), LOC_DATE) TIME_SPENT
        from LOCHIST
    ) t
    where TIME_SPENT is not null
    group by RES_ID, LOC_ZONE) f
group by LOC_ZONE
```

This accounts for multiple stays at the same location. The choice between `lag` or `lead` depends if a stay should start or end with the ping (ie, if one trailer sends a ping from A and then x hours later from B, does that count for A or B).

Comment: Nice. Bit concerning about the boundary values though. The way I understood it, the stays started/ended with change in location.